# Asking questions with obvious answers

Tags: discussion

I came across this questions today: [Olive oil instead of peanut oil to air fry potato?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/95523/olive-oil-instead-of-peanut-oil-to-air-fry-potato)

It doesn't explain why the question is being asked except that the OP is allergic to peanut oil. It's hard to understand if the concern is the flavour of olive oil or use of it in the air fryer.

At the same time, the answer seems incredibly obvious. Should questions like these be allowed on the site?

Comment: Obvious to one user isn't necessarily obvious to everyone. Or else no-one would ask anything

Comment: @Richard: I understand that, but a little bit of Googling would help answer questions that probably have tonnes of material out there. I do agree however, that some people have less knowledge than others and this is the right place to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that question is fine, and in general, I don't think I've seen questions that are *so* obvious that we should disallow them. (It'd have to be to the point of things that you can find in dictionary definitions like "what is corn?" I guess? but no one asks things like that.)

Please keep in mind that not everyone knows everything about cooking, so what may seem obvious to you may not be to others. Notably in this case, the existing answer actually is a bit misleading and overlooks a thing or two, so I don't really think we can claim that the answer is obvious.

Comment: Actually, "what is [ingredient]" is not uncommon, although usually it's a non-English language ingredient, or one that has changed its name over the years. Even in the case of corn, it may be known as "maize" elsewhere. (I'm being a bit pedantic, yes, but I do fully agree that what questions are "very obvious" is a subjective measure!)

Comment: Yeah, I struggled a bit to think of something short that couldn't be fleshed out until a legitimate question.